# Solving a vector diferential equation lead to ComplexInfinity Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

Tags: differential-equations, vector, vector-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following Vector PDE:

[image]

I implemented the following code:

```
mu0 = 4 Pi 1*^-7 // N;g = 2.2128*^5; Js = 1.13; hbar = 1.054571*^-34;  (*Defining some constants*)      
e = 1.602176634*^-19; 
pf = ( hbar/(2 e th Js ));
Heff = {Hx, 0, 0};
(* Breaks when I turn this on:;*)
(* Heff += pf (Cross[m[t],p]+n p); *)
p = {0, -1, 0};

s = NDSolve[
         {m'[t] == -(g/(1 + a^2)) Cross[m[t], Heff] 
                   - (g a)/(1 + a^2) Cross[m[t], Cross[m[t], Heff]] 
           /. {a -> 1, n -> 1, Hx -> -0.02/mu0, Js -> 1.13, th->1*^-9}
            , m[0] == {0, 0, 1} }
            , m
            , {t, 0, 15*^-9}
           ];
Plot[{Evaluate[m[t] /. s]}, {t, 0, 15*^-9}
,PlotStyle->{Green,Blue,Red}
, (*colors not changing*) 
PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

It works nicely:
[image]

But when adding an extra term to the Heff vector ***(uncommenting the 5th line)*** everything breaks down into a lot of errors:

[image]

[image]

P.D. How can I set different colors for each graph in the plot? I tried PlotStyle->{Green,Blue,Red} but it assigns colors to all the same...

Comment: I usually use a bit of trickery with `TranslationTransform[]`: `Heff = TranslationTransform[{Hx, 0, 0}][pf (TranslationTransform[n p][Cross[m[t], p]])]`. Try this and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note.** I will use slightly simplified numbers and equations to get the point across.

**The problem.** The input

```
{1,2,3}+a
```

evaluates to

```
{1+a,2+a,3+a}
```

So far so easy. The problem is that by the same logic, OP's input

```
Heff = {1,0,0}+Cross[m[t],{4,5,6}]
```

evaluates to

```
{1+Cross[m[t],{4,5,6}],Cross[m[t],{4,5,6}],Cross[m[t],{4,5,6}]}
```

Evidently Mathematica is not clever enough to understand that `Cross[m[t],{4,5,6}]` is itself a symbolic representation of a vector. But it would not be fair to say it like this, because actually Mathematica was simply being consistent and predictable, as it should be.

**A possible solution.** I am going to suggest that OP should not take advantage of `NDSolve`'s fancy support for a vector unknown. I am no fan of such fancy features, because they can be harmful as OP has demonstrated, and because Mathematica code can be quite clean without them.

Please `Quit[]` before trying this:

```
(* this is the main difference to OP's approach *)
m[t_] := {mx[t],my[t],mz[t]};

(* please inspect the result of the next line, it is what one expects *)
Heff = {1,0,0}+Cross[m[t],{4,5,6}];

(* now this looks just as clean, and it works *)
s = NDSolve[{D[m[t],t]==Cross[m[t],Heff],m[0]=={1,2,3}},m[t],{t,0,1}];

(* plot *)
Plot[Evaluate[m[t]/.s],{t,0,1}]
```

We get

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the really nice suggestion, I was having troubles also to separate each component, now everything is really swift and clean.

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar No problem. Btw, are these [NMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance) calculations?

Comment: solving the LLG equation for extra effective fields applied :D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Lifshitz%E2%80%93Gilbert_equation